# Google developer console not loading in Chromium on Debian 7

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-console-developer

I am using Debian 7 and Chromium browser.

I'm setting up OAuth authentication via google developer console, but for some reason when I enter https://console.developers.google.com, browser starts loading the page, saying "Waiting for console.developers.google.com" and is stuck forever.

Once in ~7 times it eventually loads the page, but then when I click on any tab, it freezes again.

Anyone experienced something like that?

P.S. On Windows everything's fine.

P.P.S The problem is specific for Chromium browser. Chromium also glitches with google+ notifications - they won't load.

Answer (score 1):

you can try loading Google developer console in privacy mode, meaning opening the console from https://cloud.google.com/ in an incognito window.

"*If it works there, it means one of your extensions is causing the security problem and you should remove it.*" as it explained on the Google Chome Help page :'[Fix connection errors](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6098869?hl=en).' (Your connection is not private > Tip 2: Try opening the page in incognito mode.)